# Json Searching Data Structures

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

This is my Data Structure and I'm trying to access it with simpleJason, through unity/c#, I have accidentally gotten the right data here and there, and otherwise gotten completely empty arrays, I'd like to know if my JSON file is improperly setup for my data structure, or if the parser is somehow falling though, or not properly matching what I'm looking for.

JSON File:

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
        "name" : "entertainment",
            "projects": [
                {
                "name": "Awards",
                "description": "Awards Shows",
                "credits": [
                    "Lead Engineer - Dave Jones",
                    "VFX Supervisor - John Adrian",
                    "CG Supervisor - Evan Klein"
                ],
                "meta": [
                    "awards",
                    "show",
                    "stars",
                    "red carpet"
                ],
                    "assets": [
                        {
                            "name": "Screen Actors Guild Awards",
                            "filename": "SAG_Awards.mp4",
                            "icon": "sag.png",
                            "stereo": false,
                            "meta": [
                                "Screen",
                                "Actors",
                                "Guild"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "No Awards",
                            "filename": "No_SAG_Awards.mp4",
                            "icon": "no_sag.png",
                            "stereo": false,
                            "meta": [
                                "Screen",
                                "Actors",
                                "Guild"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "None Awds",
                            "filename": "None_SAG_Awards.mp4",
                            "icon": "none_sag.png",
                            "stereo": false,
                            "meta": [
                                "Screen",
                                "Actors",
                                "Guild"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ] 
}
```

This is the struct :

```
private struct jsonAsset {
        public string category;
        public string project;
        public string description;
        public string[] credits;
        public string[] meta;
        public string asset;
        public FileInfo file;
        public FileInfo icon;
        public bool stereo;
        public bool overUnder;
    };
```

This is the function:

```
jsonAsset LoadSceneDataFromJSON(FileInfo jsonFile)
{
    jsonAsset asset = new jsonAsset(); 

    Debug.Log("Processing : " + jsonFile);

    // Parse File for Data
    var N = JSON.Parse(File.ReadAllText(jsonFile.FullName));
    var cat_arr = N["categories"].AsArray;
    asset.category = N["categories"]["name"].Value;
    Debug.Log(N["categories"]["projects"]["assets"]["filename"].Value);
    foreach (JSONNode n in cat_arr)
    {            
        asset.project = n["name"].Value;

        // Credits
        var proj_credits = n["credits"].AsArray;                   
        foreach (JSONNode pc in proj_credits)
        {
            asset.credits[asset.credits.Length] = pc["credits"].Value;
        }

        // Project Meta
        var proj_meta = n["meta"].AsArray;
        foreach (JSONNode pm in proj_meta)
        {
            asset.meta[asset.meta.Length] = pm["meta"].Value;                
        }

        // Project Array
        var proj_arr = n["projects"].AsArray;
        foreach (JSONNode nn in proj_arr)
        {
            var asset_arr = nn["assets"].AsArray;
            asset.asset = nn["assets"]["name"].Value;
            foreach (JSONNode nnn in asset_arr)
            {
                asset.asset = nnn["name"].Value;
                asset.file = new FileInfo(m_dir + nnn["filename"].Value);
                asset.icon = new FileInfo(m_dir + nnn["icon"].Value);
                var asset_meta = nnn["meta"].AsArray;
                foreach (JSONNode am in asset_meta)
                {
                    asset.meta[asset.meta.Length] = am.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return asset;                                         
}
```

Comment: What does N look like after JSON.Parse is called? Also, have you considered using Newtonsoft's JSON parser for C#?

Comment: if you want to check that a JSON file is valid you can use http://jsonlint.com/. BTW your file is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You are treating **projects** as an object instead of an array.

I dont know what JSON library you are using to give you guidance, but something like this will probably work:

```
 N["categories"]["projects"][0]["assets"]["filename"].Value
```

Comment: I wanted categories, projects, and assets all the be arrays, I thought `"projects": [
                {` did that. Since I want to allow for multiple categories, projects, or assets to be available in a .json file or spread out among files (1/.mp4)